# Cycle in directed graph

Tags: c, cs50, cycle, directed-graph

I am following the cs50 course, and in the problem set 3, I chose the tideman, but I struggle checking a cycle in the directed graph. I wrote some code but don't know why it doesn't work. It seems to me logically that it should work, please can you help me without writing any code because that would violate the academic honesty, and I don't want that.
here is what I wrote:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

bool cycle(int winner, int loser);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[j]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = j;
            printf("%i\n", ranks[rank]);
            return true;
        }
    }


    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    // for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    // {
    //     for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
    //     {
    //         preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]] = 0;
    //     }
    // }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]] += 1;
            printf("%i\n", preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else if (preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = i;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    int max_strenght = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        int temp_winner = pairs[i].winner;
        int temp_loser = pairs[i].loser;
        int index = i;
        int max_strength = preferences[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] - preferences[pairs[i].loser][pairs[i].winner];
        for (int j = i; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            int strength = preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] - preferences[pairs[j].loser][pairs[j].winner];
            if (strength > max_strength)
            {
                index = j;
                pairs[i].winner = pairs[j].winner;
                pairs[i].loser = pairs[j].loser;
            }

        }
        pairs[index].winner = temp_winner;
        pairs[index].loser = temp_loser;
    }
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if (cycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
            locked[pairs[i].loser][pairs[i].winner] = false;
        }


    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    bool is_source;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        is_source = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (j != i)
            {
                if (locked[j][i])
                {
                    is_source = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (is_source == true)
        {
            printf("%s", candidates[i]);
        }
    }
    return;
}
bool cycle(int winner, int loser)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if (pairs[i].winner == loser)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (pairs[i].loser == winner)
        {
            cycle(pairs[i].winner, loser);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Simple hints without direct answers.

Comment: "I struggle checking a cycle in the directed graph" What are the symptoms? Please also describe roughly how the program is supposed to work, without assuming that users here are aware of the details of the tideman problem. Could you create a code context in which two graphs exist, one with a cylce and one without? That would allow running/testing/debugging the shown code. It would also allow yourself to "jump in" and start simple by just finding the cycle you already know exists. Then change and try to find.. repeat. - By the way I very much respect your request for code-free help.

Comment: Did you try to use the debugger? You obviously understood what you have written (this is not always the case here...). The debugger lets you execute the code step by step and you'll be able to observe the contents of variables while you do so, etc. The learning curve may appear steep, but the time you invest in learning the basics of the debugger will quickly pay off.

Comment: I am sorry Yunnosch, I didn't make the context clear, and it's because of that that it didn't work, I just chosed the wrong variable, and for the debugger Jabberwocky, it is difficult to find a case scenario where there is a cycle, it is too complex. I have the answer now thanks!

Comment: Really? Cool. And if you have the impression that you found the answer with my help it was purely by accident. me shooting in the dark. ;-) Never mind, my pleasure. Also when it was Jabberwocky I am happy for you. Consider making an answer here.

Comment: Sometimes the smalles bit of help, even by a blind hen (possibly non-English saying...), provides a different perspective, a changed approach, and suddenly things click. It is called rubberducking and a very effective debugging technique. Compare https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ though what I actually tried to hint at for you is https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Yeah thank you very much! The journey continues!

Comment: I have an answer for this problem for another post. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767146/cs50-pset-3-tideman-lock-function-check50-says-my-lock-function-doesnt-work/76785067#76785067