# CS50 Pset 3 Tideman - lock function. Check50 says my lock function doesn't work, but it does?

Tags: c, cs50

Here is my answer for the CS50 tideman problem. For complete problem statement please visit the CS50 link at https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/3/tideman/

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];
int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO
    int j = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        while (j < candidate_count)
        {
            if (j == candidate_count || i == candidate_count - 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            while (a < candidate_count)
            {
                if (j == ranks[a+1])
                {
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
                a++;
            }
            if (c > 0)
            {
                preferences[ranks[i]][j]++;
            }
            while (c > 0)
            {
                c--;
            }
            while (a > i)
            {
                a--;
            }
            j++;
        }
        while (j > 0)
        {
            j--;
        }
        a++;
        a += i;
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    int a = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        while (j < candidate_count)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[a].winner = i;
                pairs[a].loser = j;
                a++;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else if (preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[a].winner = j;
                pairs[a].loser = i;
                a++;
                pair_count++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        while (j > 0)
        {
            j--;
        }
        j++;
        j += i;
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count - i; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] < preferences[pairs[j+1].winner][pairs[j+1].loser])
            {
                pair winner = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = pairs[j+1];
                pairs[j+1] = winner;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < pair_count; a++)
        {
            if (j == pairs[a].loser)
            {
                c++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (c == pair_count)
    {
        locked[pairs[pair_count - 1].winner][pairs[pair_count - 1].loser] = false;
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
        {
            if (i == pairs[j].loser && locked[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] == true)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                c++;
            }
            if (c == pair_count)
            {
                printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Check50 says my lock function doesn't prevent cycles. The problem is, it works when I test it. And I'm not testing with random inputs, but with the usage CS50 gives you. In `Tideman`, it's a voting system that works based on the preferences of every voter. An example is what if Alice beats Bob 7-2, Bob beats Charlie 5-4, and Charlie beats Alice 6-3. The one with the biggest victory is considered first (alice to bob), so we can image an arrow pointing from alice to bob.
[image]

Then the next biggest victory is considered, (charlie to alice) so we can add an arrow from charlie to alice.
[image]

Finally, we add an arrow from Bob to Charlie.
[image]

Since it's a loop, we don't know who the winner is. So we erase the arrow that won with the smallest victory, (bob to charlie with a 5-4 victory).

[image]

Since there are no arrows pointing to Charlie, he's the winner. To replicate this scenario, CS50 tells you to put in these inputs.
[image]

I put in these inputs, And this is what I got.
[image]

The exact same result. Charlie wins. CS50 also says that to check your work, you should also test with this input.
[image]

Heres what happens when I test it.

[image]

It's correct. So I think my codes's all good, right? But look at what check50 says.
[image]

It says that my code fails to end the cycle. But it works with their own examples. This is why I have no idea what's even wrong with it.

Comment: Perhaps you should give people time to answer on cs50.stackexchange.com before posting the exact same question here.

Comment: Also, the use of globals makes it very hard to debug.

Comment: `while (c > 0) { c--; }` - why not just `c = 0;`? Or `while (a > i) { a--; }` vs. `a = i;`

Comment: Please do not put all those pictures of plain text in your question. There is no need to use huge fonts taking whole screen just to show some output. Also those images could be way smaller. If people already get tired from scrolling down, they aren't likely to be keen to answering.

Comment: "But it works with their own examples" You only compare the output. The checker result complains about incorrect internal details. Did you check them as well? You need a debugger to do this. Normally, check50 provides details about the test data, expected result and observed result. You should look if they tell you what nodes were not locked properly.

Comment: All that check50 told me was in that final image right up there. Even if there are some incorrect internal details, i don't know what's wrong with it. I tried to implement the ending of the cycle in the line where it checks if c is equal to the pair count, and with all my tests I get the correct results. So I don't even know where to look.  And nothing is obviously wrong with the debugger either.

Comment: Not quite follow the algorithm of the lock_pairs() function. In the if statement "if (j == pairs[a].loser)", pairs[a].loser is the index of the candidate in the candidates array. So, it's in the range of [0, candidate_count), while j is the index of the pairs array in the range of [0, pair_count). pair_count = candidate_count*(candidate_count-1)/2. What does the comparison j==pairs[a].loser mean?

Comment: The point of all that was to figure out if every candidate was a loser at some point. If they were, than it would be a loop. So we make the least preferred candidate eliminated, which I did by making the last pair in the pairs array eliminated. The pairs array is sorted from my sort function, which check50 considers correct.

Comment: I understood that you were trying to find if everyone was a loser at least once. If true, there is definitely a loop. But what does it mean to compare j with pairs[a].loser? Besides, according to your function, if there is a loop, it's always caused by the last pair, so you "unlock" it to break the loop. A loop can be formed before the last pair, right? BTW, record_preferences() and add_pairs() can be significantly simplified.

Comment: Lets think of j and a as i and j for a second. (I used those variables because I already used i as a variable) If i was ever a loser, increase c by one. If c increases every single time, then theres a loop. i can only be less than candidate count, so i represents every single candidate.  we compare every candidate to see if they were a loser once. Also, it's not always caused by the last pair. My code brings out the last preference, which is eliminated. I'm not sure how record preferences and add pair can be simplified, as all the variables play an important role.

Comment: everything else aside, one should generally assume that they might test with OTHER sets of input and output that they DON'T give you in order to determine that you pass a larger more complete set of scenarios and corner cases, otherwise you could just hard code the answers to the examples they provide and say "but mine passed all the samples they provided"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly address your questions first, as one of the error messages says, lock_pairs should skip middle pair if it creates a cycle. But in your implementation, you just lock all of them to start with. Then at the end, you check if the last pair needs to be unlocked. This may be why it's failing you. Another minor thing, the sort_pairs() may potentially cause array index out of bound because you allow j to be pair_count-1. but you are referencing j+1 which will be pair_count.

The following is a complete program to show a different algorithm for the lock_pairs() function as well as how the record_preferences() and add_pairs() can be simplified. I added plenty of inline comments to help explain the algorithms. Hope this helps.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];

int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i]) == 0)
        {
            ranks[rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    //assume rank[1] and rank[2] are ith and jth candidate
    //it means this voter prefers ith candidate over jth candidate
    //hence we have preferences[i][j]++
    //so, we just need to loop through all the pairs once
    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count-1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            // just loop through all pairs and see which candidate
            // is the winner and loser
            if(preferences[i][j] == preferences[j][i])
            {
                continue;
            } else if(preferences[i][j] > preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = j;
                pair_count++;
            }
            else
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner = j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser = i;
                pair_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pair_count - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser] < preferences[pairs[j+1].winner][pairs[j+1].loser])
            {
                pair winner = pairs[j];
                pairs[j] = pairs[j+1];
                pairs[j+1] = winner;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // remember the losers found while locking in the pairs
    bool losers[MAX];

    // we need to make sure loser_count is less that candidate_count
    // if locking in a pair causes loser_count to be equal to
    // candidate_count we should skip that pair.
    int loser_count=0;

    // no one is a loser before we start
    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        losers[i] = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if(losers[pairs[i].loser] == true)
        {
            // ith pair's loser is already a loser before
            // we are not adding more losers, safe to lock the pair
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
        else if(loser_count < candidate_count-1)
        {
            // still has room for one more loser, lock in the pair
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
            losers[pairs[i].loser] = true;
            loser_count++;
        }
        // else locking this pair would form a loop
    }

    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    bool winners[MAX];

    // no one is a loser before we start
    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        winners[i] = true;
    }

    // loop through all locked pairs to find all the losers
    // record what we find in the winners array
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if(locked[i][j] == true)
            {
                winners[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // print the winner
    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if(winners[i] == true)
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```