# two issues on Tideman of CS50

Tags: c, cs50

I'm pretty new at programming and I can't find out the problem this code has.
When I run this, I have these two problems:
lock_pairs doesn't skip final pair if it creates a cycle
lock_pairs doesn't skip middle pair if it creates a cycle
And I can't understand what they mean. Please explain to me what errors they are and how can I fix them.
This is the code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
} pair;
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        // check if it does a cycle
        if (isCycle(pairs[i], 0, pairs[i].winner))
        {
            int winner = pairs[i].winner;
            int loser = pairs[i].loser;
            while (loser != pairs[i].winner)
            {
                // for every pair who doesn't have a connection with the first element of the cycle, locked it. (this is made to avoid cycles)
                locked[winner][loser] = true;
                int next_loser = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < pair_count; j++)
                {
                    if (loser == pairs[j].winner)
                    {
                        next_loser = pairs[j].loser;
                    }
                }
                winner = loser;
                loser = next_loser;
            }
        }
        // if it doesn't create cycles just put the arrow;
        else
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the core of the problem is that I misunderstood some concepts of the problem itself.

Comment: We can not help with your code if you do not explain what the code is trying to do

Comment: You might take a look at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ for something more focused on cs50.

Comment: A statement like `locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;` from a beginner shows you have a good enough understanding to begin your debugging skills too. To make it easier, you could set up trivial data to explore and then expand the input data so you can track what happens.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, I don't understand... 
1) Was the first sentence a compliment? In this case, thank you :)
2) How can i set up trivial data and expand the input data? What do these things mean?

Comment: It was. I was saying that you'll need to learn how to use a debugger very soon. And one debugging method is to work with simple data, and then expand it to check out the actions the code is intended to make. I don't know what debugging facilities cs50 offers. You might need to install a compiler such as gcc locally to do that.

Comment: ... for example you set up data with only 2 candidates.

Comment: @Gabriele Simoncini, What is `locked[]`?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767146/cs50-pset-3-tideman-lock-function-check50-says-my-lock-function-doesnt-work/76785067#76785067